# onDomReady in YUI fires before DOM is seemingly ready?

Tags: javascript, yui

I have a very peculiar situation.

I'm debugging a problem in a web app written in a fairly complicated (and slow) framework.

As part of the code, it loads and runs the following script in YUI:

```
function() {
    YU.Event.onDOMReady(function() { init(); });
}
```

where `init()` is a JS function.

**PROBLEM**: Sometimes (about 1/2 time), when init() function is called, the DOM doesn't yet seem to be loaded. More precisely, `document.getElementById();` calls return `null` value, and when I load up Internet Explorer debugger (IE8), and breakpoint on the line that does  `getElementById()` call, the HTML tab of the debugger merely says `"Loading..."`

(the app is not compatible with FireFox so I can't use Firebug)

I would appreciate any ideas on **why this might be happening** (only 50% of time) and how to approach investigating this.

if this helps, the problem started when someone made a change to the app, which involved adding a couple of things to the DOM dynamically via appendChild()

Please note that I'm looking specifically for how to address premature `onDOMReady()` call, NOT workarounds like "call `getElementById()` in a loop with setTimeout till non-null)

Comment: the elements you are trying to access with getElementByID -- are they loaded statically with the page, or via ajax?

Comment: @Matt - Statically. Part of HTML.

Comment: `document.getElementById()` should never return `undefined` (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/AxrDL/ ). If you mean it returns `null`, then say so. Since it will be almost impossible to reproduce this behaviour, extra information would be helpful: What version of IE? Have you tried other versions? What happens when you change the DOMReady event to a window load event? What happens when you change delay the DOMReady with a 0-length timer? What happens when you delay the event by a timer that approximates some time before the window load but after the DOMReady firing?

Comment: @Davin - null, fixed. IE8 - don't have access to other versions. By window load do you mean `window.onLoad`? Good idea on 0-length timer, I tried, but it didn't help - it's not a race condition issue. The latter (delay) works indirectly, see my last paragraph. Eventually, it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem is specific to IE8. It went away on IE10.
2. I fixed it by adding a small wait loop. Interestingly, the loop didn't need to be long (couple milliseconds) - I'm at a loss as to WHY this fixed the issue on IE8, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DOM `appendChild()`, use the YUI version instead..

I found that if I used `appendChild()` on the Dom object directly it didn't work in all browsers (IE7). Are you using the DOM `appendChild()` or the YUI `appendChild()` ?

Comment: DOM appendChild. I will try YUI